# The awk boundary is the beginning to a pattern

Tags: awk

How to have awk to set range or boundary of the beginning to a pattern
tried `1` fails as

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk '1,/end/ {print $0}'
a
b
c
end
e
f
g
```

this one for all as pattern works:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk '/b/,/end/ {print $0}'
b
c
end
```

but back to question how to get range or boundary of the beginning to a pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want lines between line 2 and line 4, then the following will do.

`awk 'NR ==2, NR == 4' file`

If your intention is to get lines between `regex1` and `regex2`, then you can replace NR expression with regex expression:

`awk '/regex1/, /regex2/' file`

A more verbose form would be:

`awk '$0 ~ /regex1/, $0 ~ /regex2/ { print $0}' file`

As [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647530/469418) suggests  about *full line string match* the above expression comes from that command. That answer is a compelling read.

`awk '$0 == "b", $0 == "end" { print $0}' file`

`awk '/b/, /end/' file` for what you are trying to get.

Now you can combine these two things i.e. Keeping one NR expression and one regex expression.

`awk '/b/, NR == 4' file`

or

`awk 'NR == 2, /end/' file`

`echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk '1,/end/ {print $0}'`
In this command, we should tell `awk` that it should start when line is one( When number of records is one, i.e. NR ==1);

This is:

`echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nend\ne\nf\ng\n' |awk 'NR == 1,/end/ {print $0}'`

And this will work.

Comment: I wrote this assuming second output is desired output. But in above command I didn't change NR from 1 to 2 to avoid confusion. I wanted to ask OP but couldn't do so.

Answer (score 3):

that is:

```
awk 'NR==1, /end/'
```

meaning that print from the beginning (start from first line) of the file up-to the line containing pattern *`end`*. note that *`{print $0}`* (or shortened `print`) is optional here.

#### issue with your command?

with `awk '1,/end/{ print $0 }'`, which is actually means this command `awk '1 || /end/ {print $0}'`, that is made up of two parts:

1. an always true condition which output the input line always;
2. `/end/` regex that only print the line that is matched with pattern *`end`* which is redundant when there is above condition with higher priority than this. which that command actually can be shortened to just `awk 1` (as said above `{ print $0 }` is optional).

... that cause all lines goes to output.

---

if start point is always the first line, you can write that as following too, and exit immediately as soon as the *`end`* pattern found to avoid reading rest of the file unnecessarily.

```
awk '/end/{ print; exit }1'   ##or
awk '{ print } /end/{ exit }' ##or
awk '1; /end/{ exit }'
```

and to exclude the pattern itself from printing:

```
awk '/end/{ exit } { print }' ##or
awk '/end/{ exit }1'
```

---

to do the same but match the pattern as a *string* instead of regex, and full-line string match, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1, $0=="end"'
```

see [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/4023950) for other matching options.